# How to do the program will terminate if your user input's first letter of a word is not capitalize?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make this program accepts only a user input that's been typed while following a proper capitalization. Like it won't accept "robin hood" unless it's "Robin Hood". When I run it, it says...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMD-Ryzen\Documents\PY CODEX\3.1.py", line 20, in <module>
    if x.isupper() == false:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isupper'
```

Here's my code:

```
#List of the movies
lst = ['Spidey', 'Castaway', 'Avengers', 'GI. JOE', 'Shallow']

#The data stored in this list will come from input("Name of movie") using .append
x=[]

print("Enter at least 5 of your favorite movies"+"\n")

#Loop to repeat the same question 5 times
for i in range(5):                  
    x.append(input("Name of movie:"))

#I used the set.intersection method to find the common elements between the two list
lst_as_set = set(lst)
intersection = lst_as_set.intersection(x)
intersection_as_lst = list(intersection)



if x.isupper() == false:
    print("It will never work out. Nice meeting you!")


elif len(intersection_as_lst) == 3:
    Ques = input("\n"+"Do you love some of his movies?:")
    if Ques == "yes":
        print("\n"+"You have", len(intersection_as_lst), "common fave movies and they are:")
        print(intersection_as_lst)
    elif Ques == "no":
        print("It will never work out. I dont like")
        s = set(x) - set(lst)
        print(s)

elif len(intersection_as_lst) == 0:
    Ques = input("Do you love some of his movies?:")
    if Ques == "yes":
        print("It will never work out. Nice meeting you!")
    else:
        print("It will never work out. Nice meeting you!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to apply a string [method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/) `isupper()` to a list. You must use a loop with the parameter:

```
for c in x:
    if not c[0].isupper():
        print("It will never work out. Nice meeting you!")
        break
```

Comment: One question, how will I collect those element in my list that is not capitalized. Because I want to print them

Comment: To do this, you need to completely change the body of the loop, you need to create another list (empty), go through the list using a loop with a parameter, if the element is not written with a capital letter, add it to the resulting list, then print It.

Comment: And you need to check not all characters of the string, but only the first one

Comment: It is rather difficult to organize such a check, because if the name consists of several words, and all these words must be written with a capital letter, then it is necessary to split the line into a list and check each of its elements.

Comment: Like this?
```lower_case_words=[]
for word in x:
    if word.isupper():
        lower_case_words.append(word)```

Comment: .islower rather

Comment: Yes, but the code I wrote for you in answer is not entirely correct: it checks to see if the whole word is in capital letters, not the first letter. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if list is **isupper** .
You'll need to do

```
output = []
for word in x:
    if word[0].isupper() == False:
        output.append(word)
        print("It will never work out. Nice meeting you!")
```

Comment: One question, how will I collect those element in my list that is not capitalized. Because I want to print them

Comment: Take a look at the updated code.The `output` list will collect the words that are not capitalized.

Comment: it only adds and show the first user input and not the other user input

Comment: It will do that if you end the loop after the first word. Else you can collect the words outside of loop using `output = [word for word in x if word[0].isupper() == False]`

Answer (score 1):

First in python it is **False** and not **f**alse.
and as you want to stop the program you can raise an exception

```
x = list()
print("Enter at least 5 of your favorite movies\n")
for i in range(5):
    m_name = input("Name of movie: ")
    if m_name[0].islower():
        raise 'must start with an uppercase letter'
    x.append(m_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ìs_properly_capitalized(word: str) -> bool:
    if not word:
        return False
    return word[0].isupper() and not any([c.isupper() for c in word[1:]])


results = [ìs_properly_capitalized(word) for word in lst]

if False in results:
    print("One or more words not properly capitalized")
    sys.exit(1)
```